# Boxplot legend as axis title

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

How do I add the legends of the boxplot at the bottom so that they show up as a secondary axis text line above the "Follow-up 1", "Follow-up 2" etc. line?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this using facetting?

```
# Sample data
set.seed(123);
df <- cbind.data.frame(
        y = rnorm(20),
        Group = sample(c("UT", "F", "T"), 20, replace = TRUE),
        x = sample(c("Follow-up 1", "Follow-up 2"), 20, replace = TRUE))


# Plot
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = Group));
gg <- gg + geom_boxplot();
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~ x, ncol = 3, scales = "free_x");
gg <- gg + theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank());
gg <- gg + labs(x = "x axis label", y = "y axis label");
```

[image]

---

## Update

With group labels on x-axis

```
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = y, fill = Group));
gg <- gg + geom_boxplot();
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~ x, ncol = 3, scales = "free_x");
gg <- gg + labs(x = "x axis label", y = "y axis label");
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a solution without using the facet_wrap function and have the F, T and UT as x axis text.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the group labels on the x-axis. Is this what you're after?